# Closed socket, java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm developing an application that allows the user to upload a file. The system executes a thread to do some stuff with that file. When the system has finished its work with the file, it allows the user to download a file that contains details of the process. There is no problem, but if you do that repeatedly the system crashes with an exception.

This is the stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:145)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:241)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:166)
at org.postgresql.core.QueryExecutor.executeV3(QueryExecutor.java:128)
at org.postgresql.core.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:101)
at org.postgresql.core.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:43)
at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc1Statement.java:515)
at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc1Statement.java:296)
at com.hinet.utils.db.Db.modify(Bdd.java:143)
at com.hinet.gus.service.LogService.insert(LogService.java:332)
at com.hinet.gus.service.LogService.logFile(LogService.java:441)
at com.hinet.gus.service.upload.UploadExternColectiveFile.execute(UploadExternColectiveFile.java:60)
at com.hinet.gus.service.utils.ThreadExterns.run(ThreadExterns.java:41)
```

Could you help us?

Answer (score 0):

This means something went wrong at the Server side and connection was closed. (probably a serverside exception ??)

Examine your server logs